# Can i use Selenium IDE instead of Webdriver to integrate to a CI ?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Since Selenium Webdriver needs significant DOM skills (which i lack), could i use the Selenium IDE recorded tests to provide inputs to Jenkins CI for automated regression testing ? I hope this is not closed as a subjective question.

Comment: Yes it can, but should it? No. It doesn't "understand" the web page like *you* will. What "DOM" skills do you speak of? XPath & CSS selectors? Well, how do you think *we* learnt how to use them? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This one should help you i belive: http://myselenium.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/webdriver-integration-with-jenkins/

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/aSh8xijP4V8